# custom adapter getView only gets called while debugging

Tags: android, listview, background-thread

I have an activity whose only purpose is to display a list view.  There is a custom adapter to serve up the views for each element in the array.

I have break points all over and when I debug, it stops in "count" a number of times - the first few times the return value is zero, then it changes to 3 (the correct value in this case).  Then we stop in "getView" - all the right stuff happens, and after we're through with all the break points, then presto magico all three records display on the screen.  Yea!

So then I try to run the app outside of the debugger.  I get the log message that it's visited "count", and the log message displays the return value so I know it's correct - but "getView" never gets called!!

I'm not sure which bits of code are relevant to this question & don't want to pollute the question with the entire project; please let me know if there's a specific section that would be helpful. I've researched all the "getView not called" questions but those consistently are for a case where getView *never* gets called, which clearly mine can be…sometimes :(

EDIT:  Adapter code

```
public class DivisionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DIV_ADAPT";

private ArrayList<Division> divisionList;
private Context context;

public DivisionAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Division> divList) {
    divisionList = divList;
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Integer count = 0;
    if (divisionList != null) count = divisionList.size();
    Log.v(TAG,count.toString());
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    Object o = null;
    if (divisionList != null)
        o = divisionList.get(position);
    return o;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.v(TAG,"getView");
    if (divisionList == null)
        return null;

    LinearLayout divisionView = null;
    Division thisDiv = divisionList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        divisionView = new LinearLayout(context);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        li.inflate(R.layout.division_item, divisionView, true);
    } else {
        divisionView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }
    Log.v(TAG,thisDiv.name());
    TextView v = (TextView) divisionView.findViewById(R.id.divisionName);
    v.setText(thisDiv.name());
    v = (TextView) divisionView.findViewById(R.id.divisionRegion);
    v.setText(thisDiv.region());

    return divisionView;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<Division> newList) {
    divisionList = null;
    divisionList = newList;
}

}
```

And just in case it's useful, some snippets from the activity class:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refreshList();
}

private void refreshList() {

    // use the class static query method to get the list of divisions
    Division.query(Division.class, 
            new StackMobQuery().fieldIsEqualTo("status", "ACTIVE"),
            new StackMobQueryCallback<Division>() {

                @Override
                public void failure(StackMobException arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.v(TAG, "query fail");
                }

                @Override
                public void success(List<Division> arg0) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "query success");
                    divAdapt.setList((ArrayList<Division>) arg0);
                    divAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

}
```

EDIT 2/11:
I found this question: [Markers not showing on map after stackmob query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444221/markers-not-showing-on-map-after-stackmob-query/) which reveals the hitherto unknown fact that stack mob queries run on a background thread.  I'm starting to research the relationship between threads and adapters and thought I'd share this clue in case it helps anyone else figure out what's going on here faster than I can.  TIA.

Comment: POst your getView() method/ whole adapter class.

Comment: @Sagar edited to include adapter code - thanks

Comment: also: just added an empty view as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670277/how-to-show-that-a-listview-is-empty-with-a-custom-list-adapter?rq=1) - it shows up even when count >0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk why this EVER worked in the debugger - that turned out to be a red herring.

As discovered, the StackMobModel static query method does run in a background thread, from which calling NotifyDataSetChanged() is completely ineffectual.

I ended up replacing the success method in the StackMobQueryCallback as follows:

```
                @Override
                public void success(final List<Division> arg0) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "query success");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            updateList((ArrayList<Division>) arg0);                             
                        }
                    });
                }
```

and then added this new method

```
private void updateList(ArrayList<Division> newList) {
    divAdapt.setList(newList);
    divAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

now, when the query returns, the adapter update is directed to run on the proper thread, and hooray, everything looks stitched together just fine and dandy.

whew!